# Custom field not not going into the analysis services db

Tags: ssrs-2008, olap-cube

Using the process editor, I created a new field, Product (Reportable = 'Dimention').
For all the existing bugs in TFS, I assigned values for 'Product' and saved.
The big problem is that this field does not appear in the Olap Cube. Trying to create a report via Excel gives the error,
TF208066: A PivotTable and PivotChart report for the 'Product' field will not be created. The field is not in the Analysis Services database. Click Finish to create the other reports, click Back to specify another query, or click Help for more information.
I changed 'Product' to 'AbcProduct' (thought it might already be there as part of some other project collection) but no luck. Its been 2 days which should be long enough for the cube to rebuild.
Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Its been 2 days which should be long enough for the cube to rebuild."

Did you actually manually rebuild the Cube?

[Rebuild the Data Warehouse and Analysis Services Cube](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668753.aspx)

Comment: No. I don't have permissions to force a manual rebuild. Just checked the status after the weekend and still the same problem :(

Comment: On contacting Operations it turned out that the Cube was not rebuilding at all. They are trying to sort it out. Thanks.

Comment: Np, hope you get it sorted out.  Many times the cube will not build due to permissions issues.  If your team needs help let me know.